# Powershell and Exchange: Detecting When Values Don't Need To Change

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm building a tool for handling user renaming in AD and Exchange using Powershell.

There's a section of the script that I've used in to build appropriate UPN/PrimarySMTPAddress values based on provided information that checks for conflicts with values in other AD User Objects and returns an available and appropriate value for the script to use.

To account for cases where the UPN/PrimarySMTPAddress generated from the new values collected earlier in the script may result in the new proposed UPN being the same as the current value, the script's current method of simply finding the next available appropriate UPN isn't good enough.

To try to deal with this, I added a simple If checking to see if the generated UPN value was the same as the current AD User Object's UPN, but this is failing and I'm not sure why.

Here is my current code complete with the attempt to catch the duplicate:

`$UPNGivenName` is the First Name, alpha characters and dashes only. 
`$UPNSurname` is the provided Last Name, alpha characters and dashes only.
`$SMTPDomain` is the the domain email suffix: eg *@contoso.com*
`$UserAdUpn` is pulled from the target AD object's UniversalPrincipalName. Earlier in the script I've already confirm a valid AD Object is found and pulled its UniversalPrincipalName value directly into $UserAdUpn.

```
If ($ChangeUPN -eq 'Y') {
    $ProposedUPNBase = $UPNGivenName + "." + $UPNSurname
    $checkNewUPNDupe = "$ProposedUPNBase$SMTPDomain"

    If ($UserAdUpn -eq $checkNewUPNDupe) {
        # Generated UPN matches current UPN
        Write-Host "New UPN matches current UPN. No change."
        $ChangeUPN = 'N'
    }
    Else {
```

> #... Loop for crazy UPN checking/creation stuff. Not relevant

```
    }
}
```

EDITS: (Stuff I should have thought to include to begin with, really)

The Error: Even though I know the current UPN and the proposed UPN are the same, the duplicate check doesn't trigger and a new UPN is created.

Added info on the source of UserAdUpn above.

Comment: Can you explain how it is failing? At a glance you are inserting a 0 in your $testProposedUPN and there doesn't appear to be an "@" separating the user and domain name.  I presume those queries will come back empty...  Let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: I'll get it added to question in a bit, but basically the check is failing to trigger when I know the proposed UPN value is the same as the existing, resulting in each run generating a new UPN with an incrementing value: first.last@contoso.com, first.last1@contoso.com, etc.

Comment: I presume the check won't trigger when they are the same because: `If ($UserAdUpn -eq $checkNewUPNDupe){ ... }` Where is `$UserAdUpn` defined?  Somewhat confusing because there are multiple checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a PEBKAC error to begin with, an ID10T if you prefer.

My mind was stuck reading "UPN" as "Universal Principal Name", when it is, in fact, "User Principal Name", and the error began when I used that wrong term to try to build the little check script, it of course wouldn't ever register a matching value because it was looking for a value that wasn't there to begin with.

Once I corrected the source of `$UserAdUpn` to, you know, the UserPrincipalName value, it worked just fine.

Thank you for your efforts Steven. I appreciate them.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you were getting a bloody red error because the address you were trying to test with `Get-Mailbox` wasn't found.  You can just add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to that command. It will still work in the Boolean evaluation.

```
If ($ChangeUPN -eq 'Y') {
    $ProposedUPNBase = $UPNGivenName + "." + $UPNSurname
    $checkNewUPNDupe = "$ProposedUPNBase$SMTPDomain"

    If ($UserAdUpn -eq $checkNewUPNDupe) {
        # Generated UPN matches current UPN
        Write-Host "New UPN matches current UPN. No change."
        $ChangeUPN = 'N'
    }
    Else {
        # Check for and select available UPN
        Write-Host "Finding avaialble appropriate UPN"
        $i = 0
        While (1) {
            # Check if i is >=1
            If ($i) {
                # Update username with number
                $testProposedUPN = "$ProposedUPNBase$i$SMTPDomain"
            }
            Else {
                # Otherwise, check base username (no number)
                $testProposedUPN = "$ProposedUPNBase$SMTPDomain"
            }
            # Check if user exists
            If ( (Get-ADUser -Filter { EmailAddress -eq $testProposedUPN -or  UserPrincipalName -eq $testProposedUPN }) -or 
                (get-mailbox $testProposedUPN -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue )) 
            {   # If so, increment the number and re-loop
                $i++
            }
            Else { 
                # Otherwise, update ProposedUPN to the non-existant user
                $NewUPN = $testProposedUPN
                # Exit the loop
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also shortened to 1 `Get-ADUser` command by using a `-or` in the filter.  This code tested good in my environment.

Comment: Thanks for that cleanup on the tests. I appreciate that. However, the issue is earlier in the script. I've edited the question to focus and clarify. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you can appreciate the wording is difficult to follow. Checking to see if two things are equal is just that, I wouldn't call it a duplicate check if later code is looking for "potential" duplicates. Even that later code is more duplicate prevention then checking.

At any rate, the only way the `-eq` operator is going to fail you is if operands really are different. If it isn't obvious on inspection it might be an encoding issue. I once had a long night where `-eq` looked like it was failing, but I eventually realized one of the values had a Unicode long dash that looked identical to a regular dash in the console.  Shady memory but I think I isolated it by converting the characters to numbers and checking the results by eye. Something like: `[Int[]][Char[]]$var`

I presume the comparison is only failing some of the time.  I think you need to take a very close look at the two values those don't compare as expected.

Comment: Yea, I have trouble with awkwardly worded questions too, and I'm cringing a little over this one. Writing it out usually helps me solve things that should be obvious before I hit the submit button, but it wasn't until well into my bourbon last evening that the obvious bits seemed to strike me. It is a comparison issue, and all the other stuff was unnecessary distraction. I'll probably rewrite the entire question, or get just enough ideas doing so to solve it myself, later this evening. I need to run a tests to see how the check is failing to begin with. Things I should have done first.

Comment: I will keep an eye out for further news.  I too do my best work after a drink or too LOL...